# Batch File: Search All Directories Except These Directories

Tags: batch, batch-file

I have a line of code that looks like this, which loads all immediate directory names into Variable A, then continues on through the rest of the loop.

```
for /d %%A in (*) do
```

How can I change this such that it skips over items in a pre-defined IgnoreList?  For instance:

IgnoreList: Item 1, Item 2, Item 3...note that some Items will have spaces.

Comment: I should note that I already am searching a list in this batch file for another part of it.  The list is implemented as such: Items =(Item1, Item2, Item3), basically defined in a variable.  I'd like to use the same idea and change the list within the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /b /ad c:\ |findstr /virxg:exclude.txt
```

where `exclude.txt` contains folders to ignore, one per line (wildcards possible with `findstr` REGEX):

```
Windows
Users
Program.*
Documents.*
```

If you want to do something with the results, your `for` loop could look like:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad c:\ ^|findstr /virxg:exclude.txt') do @echo %%a
```

Answer (score 0):

```bat
@echo off 

for /D %%i in (c:\*)do echo\%%~fi|findstr /ive /c:\Php /c:\Users /c:%WinDir% /c:"c:\Program Files (x86)"
```

You can do this without additional file too with multiples **`/c:"Strings"`**:

- `/C:string    Use string as a literal search string (may include spaces).:`

---

```bat
FINDSTR
Search for a text string in a file (or multiple files) unlike the simple FIND
command FINDSTR supports more complex regular expressions.
 
Syntax
FINDSTR string(s) [pathname(s)]
[/R] [/C:"string"] [/G:StringsFile] [/F:file] [/D:DirList]
[/A:color] [/OFF[LINE]] [options]
 
Key
string(s)    Text to search for, each word a separate search.
pathname(s)  The file(s) to search.
/C:string    Use string as a literal search string (may include spaces).
 
options can be any combination of the following switches:
 
/I   Case-insensitive search.
/V   Print only lines that do NOT contain a match.
```