# Command Prompt copy some (not all) folders from one drive to another?

Tags: command-line

How can I copy certain specific folders and its contents from one drive to another?

The music files on my mp3 player got corrupted, so I used the dir command to generate a text file of the folder names I want to copy. Then I formatted the SD card in mp3 player and now I want to copy over a fresh copy from my computer.

The mp3 files are organized into folders per album. I only want the particular folders (and contents) that were originally on the mp3 player. I don't want to copy my entire music collection.

First I opened command prompt and navigated to the music folder in my `C:\` The mp3 player is `E:\`.

Then I tried:

```
for %I in (Folder4 Folder17 Folder23) do copy %I "E:\music"
```

And I tried:

```
for %I in ("Folder4" "Folder17" "Ffolder23") do xcopy /s /i %I "E:\music"
```

But I just get the contents of the files and not the folders they are in.

What I want is to copy only  `Folder4` and `Folder17` and its contents from `C:\` to `E:\` and have the folders in `E:\` be named what they were named in `C:\`

Answer (score 1):

What you can try would be something like this:

- For **[command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line)**

```bat
for %i in ("C:\The\Full\Path\To\Music\Folder4","C:\The\Full\Path\To\Music\Folder17","C:\The\Full\Path\To\Music\Folder23")do RoboCopy.exe "%~i\." "E:\music\." /MOV /FP /NP /IS /Z /E
```

---

- For **[bath](/questions/tagged/bath)**/**[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**

```bat
@echo off 

for %%i in =;(
     "C:\The\Full\Path\To\Music\Folder4"
     "C:\The\Full\Path\To\Music\Folder17"
     "C:\The\Full\Path\To\Music\Folder23"
    );= do RoboCopy.exe "%%~i\." "E:\music\." /MOV /FP /NP /IS /Z /E
```

---

**Obs.:**
[image]

You can make an attempt with **`RoboCopy`**, where execution shows you the files that will be copied/moved, using with the switch **`/L`** or without  `/L`

```bat
   Test: RoboCopy.exe "C:\Music\." "E:\Music\." *.gz /MOV /FP /NP /IS /Z /E /L

   Execution: RoboCopy.exe "C:\Music\." "E:\Music\." *.gz /MOV /FP /NP /IS /Z /E /L
```

---

---

Some further reading:

- **[RoboCopy](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)**
- **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)**
- **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

Some answers that might help

- **[Renaming multiple folder using command line](https://superuser.com/questions/1562579/renaming-multiple-folder-using-command-line/1562692#1562692)**
- **[How to do a batch move and keep folder structure](https://superuser.com/questions/1569786/how-to-do-a-batch-move-and-keep-folder-structure/1570181#1570181)**
- **[Batch File: Search All Directories Except These Directories](https://superuser.com/questions/1642021/batch-file-search-all-directories-except-these-directories/1642124#1642124)**